# Regex handling multiple groups form a potentially comma delimited list

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse a comma separated list with multiple capture groups in each element via regex.

Sample Text

```
col1 = 'Test String' , col2= 'Next Test String',col3='Last Text String', col4=37
```

I've tried using various variants of this regex

```
(.*?)\s?=\s?(.*?)\s?,?
```

But it never gives me what I want or if it gets close it can't cope with there being just one element or vice versa.

What I'm expecting is a list of Matches with 3 groups

```
Match1 group 0 the whole match
Match1 group 1 col1
Match1 group 2 'Test String'
Match2 group 0 the whole match
Match2 group 1 col2
Match2 group 2 'Next Test String'
Match3 group 0 the whole match
Match3 group 1 col3
Match3 group 2 'Last Test String'
Match4 group 0 the whole match
Match4 group 1 col4
Match4 group 2 37
```

(Note I'm only interested in groups 1 & 2)

I'm deliberately making this non language specific as I can't get it to work in online Regex debuggers, however, my target language is Python 3

Thank you in advance and I hope I've made myself clear

Comment: Something like `([^,\s=]+)\s*=\s*(?|'([^']*)'|(\S+))` [should help](https://regex101.com/r/ETdDJp/2). In Python, it will work with PyPi regex library. See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##Tc7BCsIwDAbg@54i9NJmK4JO8FR8AfEyb27C2KoW5jbaHCbs3WvqRQ8h8P0Jyfym5zSWMbrXPHkCbx92ycguBAZENw1b7vJiA0FF3o0PCRqYd6znNPUfaQ5KI09tSL78PG3sTXkQ2cxACnrXkfre2tzd2LfDoLxQ15uug2kKrENuuNRxlYyyyVGuqq4KRKEhPYcIGOMH).

Comment: @Jesse that means I have to have a comma what if there's only one list element?

Comment: Yea I noticed that which is why I deleted my comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that only seems to work with PHP though

Comment: No, see [Python code](https://tio.run/##Tc7BCsIwDAbg@54i9NJmK4JO8FR8AfEyb27C2KoW5jbaHCbs3WvqRQ8h8P0Jyfym5zSWMbrXPHkCbx92ycguBAZENw1b7vJiA0FF3o0PCRqYd6znNPUfaQ5KI09tSL78PG3sTXkQ2cxACnrXkfre2tzd2LfDoLxQ15uug2kKrENuuNRxlYyyyVGuqq4KRKEhPYcIGOMH). Output is `{'col1': 'Test String', 'col2': 'Next Test String', 'col3': 'Last Text String', 'col4': '37'}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.*?)\s?=\s?(.*?)\s?,?` regex has got only one obligatory pattern, `=`. The `(.*?)` at the start gets expanded up to the leftmost `=` and the group captures any text up to the leftmost `=` and an optional whitespace after it. The rest of the subpatterns do not have to match, if there is a whitespace, it is matched with `\s?`, if there are two, they are matched, too, and if there is a comma, it is also matched and consumed, the `.*?` part is simply skipped as it is lazy.

If you want to get the second capturing group with single quotes included, you can use

```py
(?:,|^)\s*([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*('[^']*'|\S+)
```

See [this regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/ETdDJp/3). It matches

- `(?:,|^)` - a non-capturing group matching a `,` or start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `('[^']*'|\S+)` - Group 2: either `'`, zero or more non-`'`s, and a `'`, or one or more non-whitespaces.

If you want to exclude single quotes you can post-process the matches, or use an extra capturing group in `'([^']*)'`, and then check if the group matched or not:

```py
import re
text = "col1 = 'Test String' , col2= 'Next Test String',col3='Last Text String', col4=37"
pattern = r"([^,\s=]+)\s*=\s*(?:'([^']*)'|(\S+))"
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
print( dict([(x, z or y) for x,y,z in matches]) )
# => {'col1': 'Test String', 'col2': 'Next Test String', 'col3': 'Last Text String', 'col4': '37'}
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/3ouVLz).

If you want to do that with a pure regex, you can use a [*branch reset group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```py
import regex  # pip install regex
text = "col1 = 'Test String' , col2= 'Next Test String',col3='Last Text String', col4=37"
print( dict(regex.findall(r"([^,\s=]+)\s*=\s*(?|'([^']*)'|(\S+))", text)) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##Tc7BCsIwDAbg@54i9NJmK4JO8FR8AfEyb27C2KoW5jbaHCbs3WvqRQ8h8P0Jyfym5zSWMbrXPHkCbx92ycguBAZENw1b7vJiA0FF3o0PCRqYd6znNPUfaQ5KI09tSL78PG3sTXkQ2cxACnrXkfre2tzd2LfDoLxQ15uug2kKrENuuNRxlYyyyVGuqq4KRKEhPYcIGOMH) ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ETdDJp/2)).